# Deleting values between first two parentheses

Tags: excel, vba, parentheses

I have values in more than 10,000 rows which are [Name] [TypeofData] Option .

I need output which will be: [TypeofData] Option

Some function to delete [Name]?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what is the expected output?

Comment: I tried with Replace ([*]) . Expected output should be only [TypeOfData] Option.

Comment: Find the second [ and extract the text from that point. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=find+second+occurrence+of+character+in+string+excel&oq=find+second+occur&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5092j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Or try replacing `[*] [` with `[`

Comment: Question corrected, didn't notice my confusion in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MID()`:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("[",A1,SEARCH("[",A1)+1),LEN(A1)-SEARCH("[",A1,SEARCH("[",A1)))
```

`SUBSTITUTE()` also seems to work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,SEARCH("]",A1)),"",1)
```

Note: I'd wrap `TRIM()` around those just to be safe.